# Unable to read a Java file in a program

Tags: java, hashmap, try-catch, bufferedreader, filereader

I have created a Java program that reads a file and shows the same in the output. But my output is coming like unable to open file test.txt. Any help?

```
package test;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = "test.txt";

        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;

        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = 
                new FileReader(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }   

            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileName + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + fileName + "'");                  
            // Or we could just do this: 
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your test.txt file locked? Either opened for editing somewhere else?

Comment: I would guess it is unable to find the file?

Comment: Can you post the exception and show what line number it corresponds to in the code.

Comment: Which exception specifically is being thrown? What is the exception's message? (Hint, `ex.getMessage()`)

Comment: @Mechkov Its not locked and its also not opened somewhere else.

Comment: @rabbitguy yes it is unable to open the file.

Comment: The error your are getting is `FileNotFoundException`. That doesn't mean that it is there but unable to open it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the "whole" path to the file, instead of only the name. Put it like "User/.../.../test.txt".

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried doing it, But still I am unable to open my file.

Comment: Try using FileInputStream instead of FileReader. Here is a [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm) that my help you.